# Get a list of names of all global variables in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables, moodle

I'm working with Moodle and theres a lot of global variables and it seems that there's no proper documentation. First I thought like "yeah just see what `echo "<pre>",print_r($GLOBALS,1),"</pre>";` will yield". But when I try it, my browser becomes unresponsive while rendering and the rendered result is a mess. Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to use an debugger since the xdebug package is not available for the distro I'm using. (Turnkey Moodle appliance)

So my question is: Is there a way to see just the names of all global variables so that I can inspect them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest answer - open up lib/setup.php, scroll down to approx line 418 and they are all defined there.

Whilst you're at it, [Moosh](http://moosh-online.com/) can also generate a file that allows autocompletion of all the $CFG-> variables in your Moodle site (not directly answering the question, but closely related).

Answer (score 2):

maybe array_keys($GLOBALS)&

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, `$GLOBALS` is in fact the way to see all global variables.

The reason your script is dying is because you have a large number of variables, and each of them likely have many child objects (possibly even recursively).

If you just want a list of the *names* of the variables, just do `var_dump(array_keys($GLOBALS))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to get all variables in that scope, that could be in all script or in a specific function.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```